# Unable to display google thumbnail image in my website using thumbnail URL obtained from google api from admin SDK

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-admin-sdk, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to show google profile pictures as user profile pictures in my website. I am accessing the google thumbnail URL of user from G Suite admin SDK using google api.
All is well in google chrome when users logged in with their profiles.
Few people are not able to view their profile pics when accessing from Internet explorer.

I observed the thumbnail URL obtained for users that pic is showing up and others whose not. I see there is something like Public and private in the URL's. THumbnail urls with public are shown in all browsers.
Below are URL's:

https://www.google.com/s2/photos/**public**/AIbEiAIAAABECL7ptr30-bX1lwEiC3ZjYXJkX3Bob3RvKihkMDM3MGRjZTZjYmQxMmI4MGY0NGRhZDkwNzU5MGU5ODAwMGU3ZjdhMAHgm9hcA7CqN2B9onsNVSDWUG-ucA

https://www.google.com/s2/photos/**private**/AIbEiAIAAABDCJjb6eu7q_eWLSILdmNhcmRfcGhvdG8qKDAwODY0MjkxNjU1ZGJlNGJlM2RmNDM5YWEzZTM1OWFkZDQ0MThkNzcwAYdMG6tx1aB1x5lD92fhzYdeoxiU

I expect to show profile images retrieved from google in all browsers.

Comment: Have you checked [this SO post (Retrieving Google User Photo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467326/retrieving-google-user-photo)?

Comment: Yeah, I checked this. But our organization doesn't allow to read Users.photos api. I would appreciate if you can suggest any other way to get google profile image across domains..

Comment: Perhaps this might help in this situation... https://stackoverflow.com/a/62124006/5983596

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment by @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0, in G Suite the thumbnailURL can be private, especially if the user has not enabled the Google + profile (which is still active for G Suite accounts).
To resolve this issue I used a combination of Admin SDK > Directory API and People API.

**Directory API** to obtain the user id:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/{userKey}
```

where `{userKey}` should be replaced with user's primary email address, alias email address, or unique user ID. Source: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get

**People API** to get a public photo url

```
GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/{id}?personFields=photos
```

where `{id}` must be replaced with the user id obtained with the Directory API in the previous step. Source: https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get

In the sources cited, you can use "Try this API" in the sidebar on the right, as an API playground for testing.  Just accept the OAuth 2 authentication that will be requested. If authorized, you will know if your domain allows the use of the People API. I hope so and that it can help you.